# Deleted records from store keeps showing up

Tags: sencha-touch, local-storage

I have created a local store and model for remembering username and password:

**Store**:

```
ToolbarDemo.stores.localsettingsstore = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'UserSettings',
    proxy: new Ext.data.LocalStorageProxy(
    {
        id: 'data',
        proxy: 
        {
            idProperty: 'id'
        }
    }),
    autoLoad: true,
    autoSave: true,
    listeners:
    {
        beforesync: function()
        {
            console.log("SYNCING");
            console.log("Number of data: ");
            console.log(this.getCount());
        },
        datachanged: function()
        {
            console.log(this.getProxy());
            console.log("DATA CHANGED");
            console.log("Number of data: ");
            console.log(this.getCount());
        }
    }

});
```

**Model**:

```
Ext.regModel('UserSettings', {
    fields: [
        {name: 'username', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'password', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'storeUsernamePassword', type: 'boolean'}
    ]
});
```

If the user want to store the username and password, this function is invoked:

```
function setLocalUsernameAndPassword(localUsername, localPassword, bStoreUsernameAndPassword)
{
    removeLocalUsernameAndPassword(false); // Remove all previous inputs (Should just be one)
    ToolbarDemo.stores.localsettingsstore.add({username: localUsername, password: localPassword, storeUsernamePassword: bStoreUsernameAndPassword});

}
```

The store is set to autoload and autosave, so it should not be nessecary to run a .sync() on the store.

If the user chooses to not store the username and password, i remove all records from the store by invoking:

```
function removeLocalUsernameAndPassword(bClearFields)
{
    //ToolbarDemo.stores.localsettingsstore.removeAll();
    ToolbarDemo.stores.localsettingsstore.each(function(record)
    {
        console.log("Removing " + record.data.username);
        ToolbarDemo.stores.localsettingsstore.remove(record);
    });

    if(bClearFields)
    {
        Ext.getCmp("usernameField").value = "";
        Ext.getCmp("passwordField").value = "";
        Ext.getCmp("checkboxStoreUserInfo").checked = false;
    }

}
```

Afterwards i can see that the store is empty, BUT if i refresh the page (Start the app once again), all the records are back plus the one i stored.

Can anyone see what i'm missing to do this properly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a guy that had [exactly the same problem](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?119745-LocalStorage-for-Application-Settings-and-remove).
The solution:

You have to add a field with name "id", and type "int".
This makes sencha able to delete the record.

```
Ext.regModel('UserSettings', {
    fields: [
        {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'username', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'password', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'storeUsernamePassword', type: 'boolean'}
    ]
});
```

After i did this, i also had to do a store.save() after each update.